# Simple way to create a newtype float in Rust?

Tags: rust

The rust docs mention the newtype idiom and I thought to use that for a float: `struct MyFloat(f32)`. However, using it as a float can be a bit of a nuisance as-is. I thought I had found the solution in the num-derive crate, but it doesn't work:

```
#[derive(num_derive::Float)]
struct MyFloat(f32);
```

[In Rust Explorer](https://www.rustexplorer.com/b#%2F*%0A%5Bdependencies%5D%0Anum-derive%20%3D%20%22*%22%0Anum-traits%20%3D%20%22*%22%0A*%2F%0A%0A%23%5Bderive(num_derive%3A%3AFloat)%5D%0Astruct%20MyFloat(f64)%3B%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20x%20%3D%20MyFloat(1.0)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22x%20%3D%20%7B%7D%22%2C%20x)%3B%0A%7D)

These lines result in a number of errors about unimplemented traits Neg, NumCast, etc.

Do I need something else in there for it to work?

Answer (score 1):

The [`Float`](https://docs.rs/num-traits/0.2.15/num_traits/float/trait.Float.html) trait has some supertraits, and [`num_derive::Float`](https://docs.rs/num-derive/latest/num_derive/) implements none of them, only `Float` itself. Luckily, `num-derive` provides `#[derive]`s for them too:

```rust
#[derive(
    Clone,
    Copy,
    PartialEq,
    PartialOrd,
    num_derive::Float,
    num_derive::Num,
    num_derive::NumCast,
    num_derive::Zero,
    num_derive::One,
    num_derive::NumOps,
    num_derive::ToPrimitive,
)]
struct MyFloat(f64);
```

Unluckily, this still errors, because [`Neg`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ops/trait.Neg.html) is required but not implemented. You can implement it manually:

```rust
impl std::ops::Neg for MyFloat {
    type Output = MyFloat;

    fn neg(self) -> Self::Output {
        Self(-self.0)
    }
}
```